# naming Laravel events, listeners and Jobs

Tags: php, laravel, naming-conventions

I have an event called `UserWasRegistered` also I have a listener called `UserWasRegistered` from there I intned to develop job commands called:

`EmailRegistrationConfirmation`

`NotifyAdminsNewRegistration`

`CreateNewBillingAccount`

All these jobs would be executed within the `UserWasRegistered` event listener class.

Is this the correct approach or should i just have multiple listeners for `UserWasRegistered`? I feel using the jobs approach enabled me to call those "jobs" from other areas in my application at different times. e.g. calling `CreateNewBillingAccount` might be called if a user changed their details...?

Comment: Basically should a lister not call jobs. Not having the responsibility of executing tasks itself?

Answer (score 13):

I recommend to change the listener names that's more explicit about what's happening, so I'd avoid directly pairing listeners with events.

We're using an anemic event/listener approach, so listeners pass the actual task to *"doers"* (jobs, services, you name it).

This example is taken from a real system:

**app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php**:

```
    OrderWasPaid::class    => [
        ProvideAccessToProduct::class,
        StartSubscription::class,
        SendOrderPaidNotification::class,
        ProcessPendingShipment::class,
        LogOrderPayment::class
    ],
```

**StartSubscription listeners:**

```
namespace App\Modules\Subscription\Listeners;


use App\Modules\Order\Contracts\OrderEventInterface;
use App\Modules\Subscription\Services\SubscriptionCreator;

class StartSubscription
{
    /**
     * @var SubscriptionCreator
     */
    private $subscriptionCreator;

    /**
     * StartSubscription constructor.
     *
     * @param SubscriptionCreator $subscriptionCreator
     */
    public function __construct(SubscriptionCreator $subscriptionCreator)
    {
        $this->subscriptionCreator = $subscriptionCreator;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the subscription if the order is a subscription order.
     *
     * @param OrderEventInterface $event
     */
    public function handle(OrderEventInterface $event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();

        if (!$order->isSubscription()) {
            return;
        }

        $this->subscriptionCreator->createFromOrder($order);
    }
}
```

This way you can invoke jobs/services (`SubscriptionCreator` in this example) in other areas of your application.

It's also possible to bind the listener to other events as well, other than `OrderWasPaid`.

Comment: Hi, can you share the code of `SendOrderPaidNotification`? I want to know the better way of sending notification to the user as well as the admin also.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://gist.github.com/fulopattila122/5e965fdbd6df813566b4ff1f0fa4be72

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing that, but there is admin notification is missing (I understand you may not require that) but I was looking to create a notification that can be send to user and the admin also.
like Invoice Paid event occur and notification should be sent to user(your invoice paid) as well to admin (user#12 paid the invoice#123). Should i create 2 separate notifications? And call them in the listener's handle method?

Comment: @AsifMushtaq I think that's outside of the scope of this question, so off-topic. But it's up to you: you can create two separate notifications if the admin notifications differ from the customer one. Or just simply add the admin as bcc. Or you can create two separate listeners.